# How to unsubscribe http post request in Angular application?

Tags: angular, typescript, api, subscription, unsubscribe

Its a POST API created by API Gateway from AWS, however it always returns infinite repetition of arrays as you see in the below picture. How to return only one array?

[Mutiple requests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fb1FM.png)

Here's the code

**Angular**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, OnChanges, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http'; 
import { GetService } from '../get.service';
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { IonSlides, IonSlide } from '@ionic/angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage implements OnInit   {
  protected ngUnsubscribe: Subject<void> = new Subject<void>();


constructor(public http:HttpClient) {}
  @ViewChild(IonSlides,{'static':false}) slides: IonSlides;

  slideOpts = {
    initialSlide: 1,
    speed: 400
 };
public result:any
public res:any
data:Observable<any>;
ata:Observable<any>;

ngOnInit(){
}

  getdata(){


   this.ata=this.http.post("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",{"freq":1});
   this.ata.subscribe(data=>{console.log(data)})

  return   this.res




}
INDEX:any

slideChanged() {

  this.INDEX =this.slides.getActiveIndex().then(data=>console.log(data))
  return this.INDEX

}
   }
```

**HTML**

```
   <ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>
      Ionic Blank
    </ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
<p *ngFor="let a of getdata()">{{a}}</p >
<ion-card>
  <ion-card-content>
  <ion-slides  [options]="slideOpts" (ionSlideWillChange)="slideChanged()">
    <ion-slide  >
        <h1></h1>
    </ion-slide>
s


  </ion-slides>
</ion-card-content>
</ion-card>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not the API. Why am I sure about this? Because you're using Angular's HttpClient and you need quite a bit of boilerplate around it to make multiple requests.
Your issue is because **your page is renderer multiple times** while Angular's rendered manages the page layout.

The real issue lies at this line:

```
<p *ngFor="let a of getdata()">{{a}}</p >
```

Everytime that line is rendered angular calls `getdata()` issuing another request.

You must decouple the result list from the function requesting it.
From your code seems like `ata` is an `Observable`. Something like the following should work:

```
<p *ngFor="let a of ata | async">{{a}}</p>
```

Please note the `async` pipe used.

[From Angular documentation](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe)

> The `async` pipe subscribes to an `Observable` or `Promise` and returns the latest value it has emitted. When a new value is emitted, the `async` pipe marks the component to be checked for changes. When the component gets destroyed, the `async` pipe unsubscribes automatically to avoid potential memory leaks.

Of course you must call `getdata()` somewhere and usually the right place is in `ngOnInit()`.

**Side note: How to get only one response from an Observable subscription**

Since in this question there is confusion on this topic if you need to get only one response from an Observable the common way is to use `take` operator.

```
import { take } from 'rxjs/operators';

[...]

someService.getObservable(...)
           .pipe( take(1) ) // <-- take first response
           .subscribe( (r) => { ... } );
```

Comment: No , you see this line  "this.ata.subscribe(data=>{console.log(data)})" ??? it return repetitive api responses ... as its clarified in the attached picture there in the post , I just want to get one response .

Comment: @Aboulezz try to read carefully my answer :) That line gets called multiple times and is subscribing multiple times. 
You must call `getdata()` once in the `ngOnInit()` and then use the `ata` observable.
Btw, if you just want to unsibscribe from a subscriptio, you can pipe it through a `take(1)` rxjs operator or call `.unsubscribe` on the subscription itself. I add this latter tip in the answer.